# Как правильно верстать изображение на Андройд?

Tags: java, android

Всем привет. Решил попробовать написать свое первое приложение. Сразу же возник вопрос.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой шаблон. Фон в принципе понятно как сделать, сделаю через стандартные xml background. А вот как работать с изображением в центре, что бы оно пропорционально сжималось на разных смартфонах. Расскажите как вы верстаете такое? может быть есть сервис которые нарезает изображение под все устройства?

p.s Параметры шаблона Ширина 640px высота 960px

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Разбиваете на 4 элемента:

Красный фон - бэкграунд
  Логотип манчестера с черной полосой - `ImageView`
  Белая надпись - `TextView`
  Белый значок внизу - `ImageView` - изображение .9.png , с растягивающимися концами , где нет изображения. В Android Studio есть встроенный инструмент для работы с 9patch изображениями.

Все это компонуете в вертикальный `LinearLayout` , указываете вертикальный маржин (margin) для логотипа манчестера от верха и паддинги (отступы) для всех элементов. Для логотипа манчестера, текста и значка под текстом размер по горизонтали указываете - `match_parent`- занимать всю ширину , текст внутри позиционируете с помощью гравити по центру и в общем то готово.

`ImageView` делаете с прозрачным фоном.

Для подготовки двух `ImageView` можно использовать встроенный в Android Studio Asset Manager. Делаете одно изображение под максимальное разрешение (самую большую картинку) , добавляете в проект , затем `в IDE правый клик по картинке -> New -> Image Asset`.
 Там уже разберетесь - инструмент подготовит изображения под нужные плотности экрана и сам раскидает по нужным папкам.
Если вы не знакомы с поддержкой разных разрешений экрана в android - [необходимо ознакомиться](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html), в частности с выбором системой подходящего для конкретного устройства изображения.
Для `TextView` указываете размер шрифта в `sp` - этого должно хватить для масштабирования

Comment: Спасибо помогли!

Comment: @duddeniska ага , дополнил немного ...

Comment: Прекрасный ответ! Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Все размеры в dp.
Графику нарезаешь в 4 экземплярах в папки drawable

xlarge (xhdpi): 640x960
large (hdpi): 480x800
medium (mdpi): 320x480
small (ldpi): 240x320

Верстку в xml в папки layout.

Используй утилиту 9patch http://habrahabr.ru/post/113623/

Поддержка различных экранов http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Если не хочешь мучиться с растровой графикой и нарезкой, то изображения можно подключить в векторе. Для этого нужна библиотека типо [androidsvg](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/)